# tdb2.tdbcompact command line tool returns Failed to get a lock: file

Tags: jena

I'm running apache-jena-fuseki-3.13-1 and just found tdb2.tdbcompact from its bin-directory. I should run  tdb2.tdbcompact nightly to prevent my jena-fuseki from running out of disk space, but now I get error message( Failed to get a lock: file) when running it:

```
miettinj@ramen:~/jena> ./apache-jena-3.13.1/bin/tdb2.tdbcompact --loc=./apache-jena-fuseki-                        3.13.1/run/databases/test_TDB2
org.apache.jena.dboe.DBOpEnvException: Failed to get a lock: file='/srv/work/miettinj/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1/run/databases/test_TDB2/tdb.lock': held by process 6136

ps -x|grep 6136
6136 ?        Sl    30:48 /usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin/java -Xmx1200M -cp /srv/work/miettinj/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1/fuseki-server.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

"held by process 6136"

Another process is using the database. Compaction has to happen from the process using the database.

Apache Jena Fuseki Jena 3.17.0 added a function endpoint so that the administrator can ask for compaction on a running Fuseki server.

Comment: What does that function endpoint practically mean? At least  bin/tdb2.tdbcompact in 3.17.0 looks similar with 3.13.1. I need to

Comment: See https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol 
 tdb2.tdbcompact is a command line tool to work on a dataset when no process is using the dataset. You need to go through Fuseki (make an HTTP POST to the endpoint (with the dataset) or stop/exit the server and call tdbcompact.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but I still don't understand how to use the operations. This works curl -GET localhost:3030/ds/, but for instance curl -GET localhost:3030/ds/backups returns Error 404: No endpoint: /ds/backup

Comment: `/$/backup/ds` -- that's a real `/$/` -- server admin is under `/$/`.